# Why is assert not working in abstract class?

Tags: python, class, abstract, assert, assertion

I need you assistance to understand why `assert` is not working in my code (I am using this code to learn about abstract classes, getters and setters), I am a newbie at abstract classes.

If I put a negative number at power attribute, the code should be stop with a warning, but assert ignores if power is negative, zero or non-negative number.

Another test code without concrete methods at base class, but the same concrete methods at subclasses the code stop and give me a warning.

Here is my complete code to tests.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Load(ABC):
    #That's a class to create load to circuits.
    @abstractmethod
    def __init__(self, power=0, power_factor=1):
        self.__power = power
        self.__power_factor = power_factor

    # the attributte name and the method name must be  same
    # which is used to set the value for the attributte
    @property
    def power(self):
        return self.__power

    @power.setter
    def power(self, power):
        # AT TEST SHOULD STOP HERE ANY CONDITION - ONLY TEST PURPOSEs
        # BUT HERE ASSERT IS IGNORED
        assert (power < 0), "power must be non-negative"
        assert (power >= 0), "***power must be negative - ONLY TEST"
        self.__power = power

    @property
    def power_factor(self):
        return self.__power_factor

    @power_factor.setter
    def power_factor(self, power_factor):
        assert 0 < power_factor <= 1, "power factor must be greater 0 until 1"
        self.__power_factor = power_factor


class Specific(Load):
    def __init__(self, power, power_factor):
        super().__init__(power, power_factor)
    # the attributte name and the method name must be  same
    # which is used to set the value for the attributte

### ONLY TESTs PURPOSE

a = Specific(-11,1) # TO FORCE THE ERROR
print(a.power, a.power_factor)
a.power_factor = .4
print(a.power, a.power_factor)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You are not using your setter - you directly assign to your backing fields.

Use

```
class Load(ABC):
    #That's a class to create load to circuits.
    @abstractmethod
    def __init__(self, power=0, power_factor=1):
        self.power = power                          # acutally use the setter, do not
        self.power_factor = power_factor            # set the backing field directly...
```

so your setters check the values.

Comment: It's worth clarifying that the assumption that setters and getters will just work in python once they're there is horrendous. Getters and setters in python are just regular functions and if you can still access values directly so you have to explicitly make use of them and maybe even enforce their usage if you want them to work properly.